# How to access form_for nested attributes on controller after form submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to access the fields_for nested attribute but I keep getting this error:

`undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

**For line:**

`braintree_account_params[:braintree_subscription_attributes][0][:plan_token]`

**I have tried:**

```
params[:braintree_subscription_attributes][0][:plan_token]
params["braintree_subscription_attributes"][0]["plan_token"]
braintree_account_params[:braintree_subscription_attributes][0][:plan_token]
braintree_account_params["braintree_subscription_attributes"][0]["plan_token"]

params[:braintree_subscription_attributes]['0'][:plan_token]
params["braintree_subscription_attributes"]['0']["plan_token"]
braintree_account_params[:braintree_subscription_attributes]['0'][:plan_token]
braintree_account_params["braintree_subscription_attributes"]['0']["plan_token"]
```

None have worked

This:
`params[:braintree_account][:braintree_subscription_attributes].first[:plan_token]`

Error: `Undefined method first # for ActionController`

**My params:**

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "braintree_account"=>{"first_name"=>"asfd", "last_name"=>"asfd", "braintree_subscription_attributes"=>{"plan_token"=>"4zfr"}}, "user_id"=>"1"}
```

Strong Params:

params.require(:braintree_account).permit(..., braintree_subscription_attributes: [:id, :plan_token])

**Models:**

```
class BraintreeAccount < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :braintree_subscription
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :braintree_subscription
end

class BraintreeSubscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :braintree_account
end
```

How can I access `plan_token`?

Comment: Please provide your full controller(s) code, as the solution lies there.

Comment: The `params` you post, that is what you should use/investigate to find how to access the posted `braintree_subscription`. Then, furthermore: make sure that your strong params do not block the required fields (but that seems to be ok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is a has one, and not a has many, you won't have more than 1 nested object in your attributes.  The array syntax is only necessary if there is expected to be more than 1 child.

```
braintree_account_params[:braintree_subscription_attributes][:plan_token]
```

Comment: Also easy to verify against the posted params, imho this is correct.